# Pandas duplicate data between 2 dates

Tags: python, pandas, date

I'm trying to find a method of duplicating all of the data in a row for every month between dates. Start date and end date.

This is the dataset:

| ID | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1007 | 2022-03-01 | 2022-08-01 |
| 1008 | 2019-11-01 | 2020-02-01 |

What I would like to do is repeat the row, incrementing the date, every month between the start and end values.
Example outcome:

| ID | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1007 | 2022-03-01 | 2022-08-01 |
| 1007 | 2022-04-01 | 2022-08-01 |
| 1007 | 2022-05-01 | 2022-08-01 |
| 1007 | 2022-06-01 | 2022-08-01 |
| 1007 | 2022-07-01 | 2022-08-01 |
| 1007 | 2022-08-01 | 2022-08-01 |
| 1008 | 2019-11-01 | 2020-02-01 |
| 1008 | 2019-12-01 | 2020-02-01 |
| 1008 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-02-01 |
| 1008 | 2020-02-01 | 2020-02-01 |

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can move in all row data and check data_start is preset start duplicated and when present the date_end can you exit the loop
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to do it

create a range from start and end dates, then use explode.

```
df=df.assign(Start=df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x['Start'], x['End'], freq='MS').strftime('%Y-%m-%d').tolist(), axis=1)).explode('Start').reset_index()
df.drop(columns=['index'], inplace=True)
df
```

```
      ID         Start        End
0   1007    2022-03-01  2022-08-01
1   1007    2022-04-01  2022-08-01
2   1007    2022-05-01  2022-08-01
3   1007    2022-06-01  2022-08-01
4   1007    2022-07-01  2022-08-01
5   1007    2022-08-01  2022-08-01
6   1008    2019-11-01  2020-02-01
7   1008    2019-12-01  2020-02-01
8   1008    2020-01-01  2020-02-01
9   1008    2020-02-01  2020-02-01
```

Answer (score 0):

for this one, I think you're going to want to use both `pd.date_range()` and `DataFrame.explode()`, so you can get away with only expanding the DataFrame once. Using the out-of-the-box frequency of `month_start` (for other aliases, you can check [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-offset-aliases)), your question is actually pretty straight-forward. I am sure someone will have a better idea than the `.apply` I used, though.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [1007, '2022-03-01', '2022-08-01'],
        [1008, '2019-11-01', '2020-02-01'],
    ],
    columns=['ID', 'Start', 'End'],
    dtype=pd.DatetimeTZDtype
)
df['Start'] = df.apply(
    lambda x: pd.date_range(x['Start'], x['End'], freq='MS', closed='left'),
    axis=1,
)
df = df.explode(column='Start')
```

We're overwriting the `Start` column with a date range from your start to end dates (start-date inclusive), then exploding the dataframe to add one row per month in between date boundaries.